# Linguex and beamer: how to get sans serif font with indexed brackets?

Tags: beamer, linguex

I use linguex to make a presentation with the beamer class. When I use the option to get indexed brackets \exi. the subscripted labels on the brackets appear in roman font. How can I get them to appear in sans serif font like the rest of the example?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{linguex}
\renewcommand\eachwordone{\sffamily} %sans serif in glossed examples
\renewcommand\eachwordtwo{\sffamily} %sans serif in glossed examples

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]

\exi.       She disappeared [ADVP very [ADV quickly]]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `linguex.sty` I'd say that the culprit is the line 338

```
\def\labelBr#1 {\mbox{$\hspace{.05em}_{\mbox{\scriptsize\rm#1}}$} }
```

The `\rm` is doing what you see. If you want sans-serif font you should replace `\rm` by `\sffamily`, i.e. put the line

```
\def\labelBr#1 {\mbox{$\hspace{.05em}_{\mbox{\scriptsize\sffamily#1}}$} }
```

somewhere after `\usepackage{linguex}`. On a safer side, you could better write

```
\def\labelBr#1 {\mbox{$\hspace{.05em}_{\mbox{\scriptsize\normalfont#1}}$} }
```

In this case you would get roman font if e.g. `\usefonttheme{serif}` is used.